# Cant get textbox values to multiply together into a third

Tags: java

Im currently working on a simple program to show the contents of a database. Im not sure how to get two of the textbox values to multiply together and put the result in the third. THis is the section of code:

```
private void GetProductTable() {
    ResultSet rs = GetProducts();

    try {
        jTable2.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    jTable2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            JTable target;
            target = (JTable) e.getSource();

            int row;
            row = target.getSelectedRow();

            String[] result;                
            result = getRowAt(target, row);



            ProductID.setText(result[0]);
            ProductName.setText(result[1]);
            ProductSupplierID.setText(result[2]);
            ProductCataID.setText(result[3]);
            ProductInStock.setText(result[4]);
            ProductOnOrder.setText(result[5]);
            ProductReorderLvl.setText(result[6]);
            ProductDiscon.setText(result[7]);
            ProductUnitPrice.setText(result[8]);
            ProductUnitPrice1.setText();
        }

    });

}
```

I need result[5] to multiply by result[8] and put the total in ProductUnitPrice1. The results are being retrieved from an external database. I have tried a few things and i just cant get it to work, all I keep getting is the contents or result 5 and 8 both put into the box. I know I need to get it to look at the results as a integer and not a string but everything I have tried has not worked.

This may be a really simple solution but I am very much a beginner and I need this to work in order to pass the Java unit in my HND.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried a few things". **What** have you tried?

Comment: I assume from your question that `result` contains Strings, right? Have you tried to convert them to numbers by the likes of `Double.parseDouble(result[5])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
int result=Integer.valueOf(result[5])*Integer.valueOf(result[8]);
ProductUnitPrice1.setText(result);
```

you might need to change datatypes to doubles. maybe this works too:

```
ProductUnitPrice1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(result[5])*Integer.valueOf(result[8])));
```